# Why are all invariant generic class positions invariant in type parameter lists in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, invariance

I'm a bit perplexed by the strictness of the typechecker below — it seems that the invariant `T` position of `Inv[T]` is also invariant within `Variantish`'s parameter list:

```scala
scala> class Inv[T]
defined class Inv

scala> class Variantish[+T, +TVar <: Inv[T]]
<console>:12: error: covariant type T occurs in invariant position in type  <: Inv[T] of type TVar
       class Variantish[+T, +TVar <: Inv[T]]
                             ^
```

Variant types can normally occur in what look like invariant argument-list positions legally, e.g. with object-protected visibility:

```
class Variantish[+T](protected[this] var v: Inv[T])
```

and it seems that the following would be just as typesafe:

```
class Variantish[+T, +TVar <: Inv[T]](protected[this] var v: TVar)
```

Need that check mentioned above be so strict?

Answer (score 1):

From the language [specification](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#conformance) (emphasis mine), about conformance (ie `T'` is a super-type of `T`):

> Type constructors `T` and `T′` follow a similar discipline. We characterize `T` and `T′` by their type parameter clauses `[a1,…,an]` and `[a′1,…,a′n]`, where an `ai` or `a′i` may include a variance annotation, a higher-order type parameter clause, and bounds. Then, `T` conforms to `T′` if **any** list `[t1,…,tn]` -- with declared variances, bounds and higher-order type parameter clauses -- of valid type arguments for `T′` is also a valid list of type arguments for `T` and `T[t1,…,tn]<:T′[t1,…,tn]`.

This is really difficult to understand (IMHO), but I believe it means that for `Variantish` to be covariant in `T`, you would have to be able to write

```
Variantish[Dog, TVar] <: Variantish[Animal, TVar]
```

for **any** `TVar` for which `Variantish[Animal, TVar]` makes sense. But this doesn't even make sense (let alone have any truth value) for some of those `TVar`, such as `Inv[Animal]`. That's why it is forbidden in that place.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand @cyrille-corpet's answer so I expanded it with some examples.

```
class Inv[T]
class Variantish[+T, +TVar <: Inv[T]]

trait Animal
class Dog extends Animal

class AnimalInv extends Inv[Animal]
class DogInv extends Inv[Dog]

val a: Variantish[Animal, Inv[Animal]] = new Variantish[Animal, AnimalInv]
val b: Variantish[Animal, Inv[Animal]] = new Variantish[Animal, DogInv]
val c: Variantish[Animal, Inv[Animal]] = new Variantish[Dog, AnimalInv]
val d: Variantish[Animal, Inv[Animal]] = new Variantish[Dog, DogInv]
```

`a` is valid since `Animal` <: `Animal` and `AnimalInv` <: `AnimalInv` are both true.

`b` is invalid since `DogInv` <: `AnimalInv` is false.

`c` is valid since `Dog` <: `Animal` and `AnimalInv` <: `AnimalInv` are both true.

`d` is invalid since `DogInv` <: `AnimalInv` is false.

So as these show `TVar` cannot be covariant.

Even in the case of `d` where the dynamic type is valid, it is not a subtype of the static type.

I suspect if we looked at all the places where we may be using `TVar` in `Variantish` then it doesn't need to be a type parameter. As @concat pointed out any variance errors you may encounted can be solved by using the object-protected access modifier.